# 'require': cannot load such file -- script/../config/boot (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, cas

Trying to run the example available in [rubycas-client](https://github.com/rubycas/rubycas-client) using the following comman

```
     $ ruby script/server
```

But getting the following error.

```
     /home/xxxxx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in 'require': cannot load such file -- script/../config/boot (LoadError) from /home/xxxxx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in 'require' from script/server:2:in '<main>'
```

Comment: have you tried another path for that file?

Answer (score 0):

Try `rails s` from the project root directory.

The command you tried is the Rails 2 way to start the server.
Although the rubycas-client project might have that command...